# How to programmatically get/set row and column number in a GridView in WP8.1

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-phone-8.1

I am new in windows phone development. As the title mentioned,

-how do I get the row number and column number of a GridView item?

-Same as previous, how do I set the the row number and column number of a GridView item?

I need to insert a GridView item into specific row and column from code behind.

Any help is appreciated. I need some helps badly. Thanks! =(

This is my front end code.

```
<GridView x:Name="gvMap"
   ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}">
</GridView>
```

And this is my code behind.

```
    private void GenerateMap(int length, int width)
    {
        ObservableCollection<int> coll = new ObservableCollection<int>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= length*width; i++)
        {
            coll.Add(i);
        }
        gvMap.DataContext = coll;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to bind your gridview to a datasource. Never come across a situation where you wouldn't.

Hence I would get the DataSource, insert the appropriate item, then databind to the gridview again.

Sort the list or enumerable bound to the DataSource in which ever method you want to get the inserted item to appear where you want.

Comment: Yes, I am binding my gridview to a datasource. My datasource is a List<int> object. By binding it, I have created a 2D gridview.  However, what I want to do is insert an item into specific column and row. Is there any way? 
By the way, thanks for quick reply. I appreciated it.

Comment: Well you would bind list of objects. E.g. create a new class (e.g. Example) and put in your properties. Then bind to a = new List<Example>(); etc.